# Why do i need to give input twice in order for the code to run

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple bit of code to get a piece of text outputted a certain amount of times accoring to user input, however when running in terminal, i need to type in the number twice (so e.g. : 5 [enter] 5 [enter], then the text would be output 5 times).
Just wondering why this is and how to fix this, many thanks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    int i;
    cout << "How many times do you want me to say [London Town], Numbers only" << end;
    while (true) {
        cin >> x;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "Please type a number not text" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize > ::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        } else break;
    }

    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        std::cout << "London Town \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Could it be that you have one `cin >> x` before the `if` and one after?

Comment: The first `cin >> x;` is tested for validity, then the result is discarded. The second `cin >> x;` is not tested for validity and used regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read into x two times, so you need to enter it twice.
You can fix this by removing one of the `cin >> x`'s.

e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    int i;
    cout << "How many times do you want me to say [London Town], Numbers only" << end;
    while (true) {
        cin >> x;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "Please type a number not text" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        } else break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        std::cout << "London Town \n";
    }
}
```

The `int i;` in main is not used, so you could also remove it.
If you want you can also combine the `while` loop with the if statement.

e.g:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << "How many times do you want me to say [London Town], Numbers only" << std::endl;
    
    int x;
    while(!(std::cin >> x)) {
        std::cout << "Please type a number not text" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        std::cout << "London Town \n";
    }
}
```

[example godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bGPja9z5d)